# How do I upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 to most recent version through virtual machine?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Hello all I am fairly new to Ubuntu however I was not able to find an answer to this. I currently run windows 7 through which i run a program called truecrypt. Through Truecrypt i have created a hidden archive and now i am using VMware oracle to run a virtual machine i have two machines one firewalled with damn small linux and the other running Ubuntu 10.10.0 here is my problem although i am currently connected to the internet through this machine when i go to upgrade to current version of Ubuntu I get this message

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

needless to say quite a problem seeing as it does not upgrade a prompt response appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 has reached the end of life, meaning it is no longer supported.

You have two choices.

1. Do a fresh install of a newer version.
2. Update and upgrade it.
   If you opt for this, then you will have to update your sources list first.

Run `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/souces.list` in a terminal and add these lines:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo do-release-upgrade`.